# Syntax error. Missing ')'

Tags: formula

I'm trying to create a validation rule but it's erroring due to a missing parenthesis.

```
  Plan_Required__c = "Naked Fibre" &&
  NOT(Selcomm_Internet_Plan_ID__c, "906", "931", "962", "963", "964", "969", "1013", "1014", "1017", "1018", "1020") &&
  NOT(ISBLANK(Selcomm_Plan_ID__c))
```

For reference, Plan_Required__c is a multi select picklist and Selcomm_Internet_Plan_ID__c & Selcomm_Plan_ID__c are both free text fields.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting is misleading. There are two main issues with your attempt.

- Picklist and Multipicklist fields can't appear on their own. You need to use a function like `TEXT()` or `ISPICKVAL()`. For mulipicklists, you can use `INCLUDES()` if simply having your specified option is fine (i.e. if it's one of 1 or more selected values for that multipicklist)
- In general, you cannot compare a single field against multiple values. You've gotta do each check separately, and then use `OR()` (which returns true if *any* of the conditions it contains are true). e.g. `OR(x = 1, x = 2, x = 3, ..., x = 10)`

There is an exception to  the "cannot compare against multiple values" thing. When it's a text field (or can be reasonably converted into text), we can kinda bend the `CONTAINS()` function to say "return true if our field matches any of these values".

So for the second item, you could do

```
NOT(
    CONTAINS(
        "906|931|962|963|964|969|1013|1014|1017|1018|1020", 
        Selcomm_Internet_Plan_ID__c
    )
)
```

The pipes (i.e. `|`) are a *delimiter*. It doesn't need to be a pipe, though that is the most common. It just needs to be something that doesn't appear in the text that you're trying to match. You need a delimiter to separate each individual target string that you want to try to match. Note that this only works when your field contains a single one of those values. If `Selcomm_Internet_Plan_ID__c` could be `906 & 1013`, then this approach would not work.

As a pair of final notes:

- The [documentation on formula operators and functions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions.htm&type=5) is your friend. It's a good thing to reference. It'll tell you what different functions are available, what they do, and they usually give an example or two of how to use them
- Validation rules prevent records from being saved *when the result of the formula is true*. This is kinda backwards from how most people assume it works (and a better name for these would be *invalidation* rules).

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive reply! This has resolved my issue, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Derek F is right!

Your formula should be like this -

INCLUDES(Plan_Required__c,'Naked Fibre') &&
NOT(ISBLANK(Selcomm_Plan_ID__c)) &&
NOT(
CONTAINS(
"906|931|962|963|964|969|1013|1014|1017|1018|1020",
Selcomm_Internet_Plan_ID__c
)
)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I was specifically trying to avoid giving a full solution. My hope was that OP would be able to take what I wrote and arrive at this conclusion on their own (the hope being that after just a _little bit_ more struggle, they'd get there and would learn more in the process).